# Problems with wifi and mobile data after adb

Tags: adb, wi-fi, mobile-data

This is problem I faced with: I was need to test a few features in a test app but my emulator had troubles with wifi connection so I decided to upload the app on my own cell phone through adb install "app".
After I setted up the proxy - `adb shell settings put global http_proxy "ip":8181` (i was need to intercept a few request from the tesp app)
and the last thing I did were `adb tcpip 9090` and `adb connect "ip":9090` (for connecting over wifi).

That's all I did and the internet connection on my phone just disappeared (wifi and mobile data). I tried to reset networks setting but It doesn't working at all ofс I can do full reset but it's my plan "B" :)

But my telegram and WhatsApp works (I can text in it but when I try to search something my browser tell me: "No internet connection"

Comment: Remove the global proxy you set.

Comment: Thanks bud! This command `adb shell settings put global http_proxy :0` will remove the proxy am I right?

Comment: Yes. Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58450854/9165920).